# Foreign key based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have one database having following tables: `Comments`, `Articles`, `Videos`, `Songs`, `Games`, `Books` with one-to-many relationships between `Comments` and the others (an Article, Video, Song... may have many comments). I have a associative table `CommentBelongsTo` having three columns `comment_id`, `page_type`, `page_id`), for example if `page_type = 'article'` and `page_id = 1`, means the comment belongs to the article with id = 1. The question is how can i set `page_id` to be foreign key depending on the `page_type`? Or is there any better table design?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Following table structure can solve the issue

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`article`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`article` (
  `idArticle` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idArticle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`games`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`games` (
  `idGames` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGames`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`comments`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`comments` (
  `idComments` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `g_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comment` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idComments`),
  KEY `FK_Comments_1` (`a_id`),
  KEY `FK_Comments_2` (`g_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Comments_1` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `article` (`idArticle`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Comments_2` FOREIGN KEY (`g_id`) REFERENCES `games` (`idGames`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into article values (1,'A1');
insert into comments values (1,1,null,'A1 comment')
insert into games values (1,'G1');
insert into comments values (1,null,1,'G1 comment')

select * from comments where a_id<>'NULL';
```

To get the comments for particular type